# Vector from other two vectors pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, vector, series

I can't find solution for my problem. I have two vectors pandas.Series type `T = [a1, a2, a3,....,an] M = [b1, b2, b3,...bn]` I need to create new vector in which every element should be the minimum between two elements in the given vector. It should looks like `new_vector = [min(a1, b1), min(a2, b2), ....min(an, bn)`
Is this possible with the functions in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, can use pandas `min()` function to return lowest value per element position

### Minimum Value Comparing Each Element of Pandas Series

```
import pandas as pd
T = pd.Series([6,7,4,1,4,1,6,8,0])
M = pd.Series([5,3,8,1,3,7,1,7,1])

new_vector = pd.DataFrame([T,M]).min()
print(new_vector)
```

**Results:**

```
idx  minValue
0    5
1    3
2    4
3    1
4    3
5    1
6    1
7    7
8    0
```